# Ubuntu will not print black

Tags: printing, fonts

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a Toshiba Satellite P755. I print on a HP Deskjet 3752 with usb. The printer will put out normal info sheet. ANY document sent from the laptop prints WHITE for any black output. Color is fine. The only way I found out is a sheet with a grey background and black font put out the grey background with white font. I can literally print wireless from my phone perfectly fine. I searched and have not found anything specific. I tried uninstalling printer but didn't help. If I use any font color other than black, it prints that color.

Thank you.
Mike